# Sharing data between docker containers without making data persistent

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have a docker-compose file with two containers:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: someimage:fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/var/www/html

  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/var/www/html

volumes:
  myvolume:
```

The app container contains the application code in the `/var/www/html` directory which gets updated with each version of the image, so I don't want this directory to be persistent.

Yet I need to share the data with the nginx container. If I use a volume or a host bind the data is persistent and doesn't get updated with a new version. Maybe there is a way to automatically delete a volume whenever I pull a new image? Or a way to share an anonymous volume?

Answer (score 0):

i think its better for you to use anonymous volume

```
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to be willing to drop back to docker-compose version 2 and use data containers with the `volumes_from` directive.

Which is equivalent to `--volumes-from` on a `docker run` command.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial solution, but it can't be good practice to use an old version and eventually version 2 won't be supported any more. Is there any way to achieve the `volumes_from` functionality in Version 3?

Comment: Using Compose version 2 is actually just fine (there are some `docker run` configurations that Swarm-oriented version 3 doesn't support).  But `volumes_from:` is generally considered bad practice (_which_ volumes will it mount and where?), and it has the same problems you initially cite with volumes in general (they hide image content and never update).

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine. The problem isn't with docker. You can use volumes to communicate in this way. If you run `docker-compose up` in a directory with the following compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  one:
    image: ubuntu
    command: sleep 100000
    volumes:
      - vol:/vol
  two:
    image: ubuntu
    command: sleep 100000
    volumes:
      - vol:/vol
volumes:
  vol:
```

Then, in a 2nd terminal `docker exec -it so_one_1 bash` (you might have to do a `docker ps` to find the exact name of the container, it can change). You'll find yourself in a bash container. Change to the /vol directory `cd /vol` and then `echo "wobble" > wibble.txt", then` exit` the shell (ctrl-d).

In the same terminal you can then type `docker exec -it so_two_1 bash` (again, check the names). Just like last time you can `cd /vol` and type `ls -gAlFh` you'll see the wibble.txt file we created in the other container. You can even `cat wibble.txt` to see the contents. It'll be there.

So if the problem isn't docker, what can it be? I think the problem is that nginx isn't seeing the changes on the filesystem. For that, I believe that setting `expires -1;` inside a location block in the config will actually disable caching completely and may solve the problem (dev only).

Comment: My problem is not the sharing of data between containers, but making it non-persistent. In your example, let's say a new `ubuntu` image already had some contents in the `/vol` directory. I would never see those contents because they would get overwritten with the contents in the volume. I need the contents in my volume to get updated with content from the image whenever I pull a new version of the image.